# Is it possible to have a back and forth button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have 10 pages, I could easily have 10 different links sitting at the bottom of the page but that takes up valuable space, especially when developing for tablet.

Is it possible to just limit my buttons to just two? (back and forth in a linear fashion page1, page2, page3, page4 etc.)

Sort of similar to a carousel where each button would go back and forth without refreshing the page but switching out the content.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: This is the code I have at the moment which switches out the content.

```
// handle menu clicks
$('div#nav ul li a').click(function() {
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$content.slideUp("slow", function() {
  $content.load('content/' + page + '.html', function() {
    $content.slideDown("slow");
   });
})

return false;
});
});
```

Comment: It *is* possible, but... it requires writing code, and that depends on your application.

Comment: Well I'm aware it requires writing code but I am unable to figure out what needs to be done. Would you like to see my current code I'm using for switching out content ?

Comment: That could be useful, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a slider, then place iframes of your pages inside your slides.